# How to link two plots in R using Crosstalk and Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, crosstalk

I am trying to link two plotly plots in R using Crosstalk. Can someone please tell me why the example below is not working when I try to do a rectangular selection on one of the plots:

```
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)

mtcars_sd <- SharedData$new(data = mtcars, key = rownames(mtcars))

p1 <- plot_ly(data = mtcars_sd, x=~mpg, y =~drat) %>% 
    add_markers()


p2 <- plot_ly(data = mtcars_sd, x=~wt, y =~hp) %>% 
    add_markers()

mtcars_linked_plots <- plotly::subplot(p1, p2, titleX = TRUE, titleY = TRUE) %>% 
    hide_legend() 

mtcars_linked_plots %>% 
    highlight(on = "plotly_click")
```

I could use the `plotly_selected` option for `on` in `highlight` but I want the plot to resize the axes on selection that is why I am using `plotly_click`

Comment: Works fine on my machine. When I click on one point the respective point in the other plot gets highlighted as well.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I am trying to do a rectangular selection and not just highlight a point. Any ideas?